# How to restore text control from resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

If called method

```
CWnd::SetWindowText("some text");
```

How to restore default text from resource (.rc file)?

Comment: Save it before you change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, the question is not about an .rc file, but about a dialog resource of the running executable file. In this case, I don't thing that there are API functions for that, but you can parse the resources manually.

First, get the pointer to the desired dialog resource by using `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource`. Then, parse the data manually, and grab the information that you need.

Read about the format of the dialog resource e.g. [here](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/resfmt.txt), under **4.4 Dialog Box Resources**.

Answer (score 3):

No way to restore the text after you changed it, save it before doing that

```
CWnd::GetWindowText(/*Output buffer*/, /*maximum number of character to be copied*/);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db50wx7h.aspx